# Transpose Multiple Variables to Columns Suffixed with Dates

Tags: sas, transpose

I have data that looks like this:

```
data have;
    format date monyy.;

    input date:date9. group$ value1 value2;
    datalines;
01JAN2020 A 100 10
01FEB2020 A 200 20
01JAN2020 B 300 30
01FEB2020 B 400 40
;
run;
```

But I need it to look like this, where `value1 value2` are suffixed with `date`. This format is being used to export to Excel.

```
data want;
    input group$ value1_JAN20 value1_FEB20 value2_JAN20 value2_FEB20;
    datalines;
A 100 200 10 20
B 300 400 30 40
;
run;
```

I have tried `PROC TRANSPOSE`, but the actual values of `value1 value2` are stored as date names with the names of `value1 value2` stored in the column `_NAME_`.

Is there a way to do this with `PROC TRANSPOSE`, or is this only a data step/macro solution?

```
proc transpose data  = have 
               out   = try 
               delim = '_'n 
               name  = date;
    by group;
    id date;
    var value1 value2;
run;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Transpose twice. First to get a truly vertical structure. Then to generate the structure you want.

```
data have;
  input date :date9. group $ value1 value2;
  format date monyy.;
datalines;
01JAN2020 A 100 10
01FEB2020 A 200 20
01JAN2020 B 300 30
01FEB2020 B 400 40
;

proc transpose data=have out=tall;
  by group date ;
  var value1-value2;
run;

proc transpose data=tall out=want(drop=_name_) delim=_;
  by group;
  id _name_ date ;
  var col1 ;
run;
```

Results:

```
                value1_    value2_    value1_    value2_
Obs    group     JAN20      JAN20      FEB20      FEB20

 1       A        100         10        200         20
 2       B        300         30        400         40
```

Comment: Perfect! Exactly what I needed. Thank you!